# html5 app audio not working

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, audio

this code does not seem to work when I test it in the ipad (HTML5 app). This works in web browsers though... Do anyone of you have a workaround for this? I only need to make it work for the iOS devices especially for the iPAD.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title>Disc</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    img {
        position:relative;
    }
    #cover {
        height:200px;
        width:150px;
        top:150px;
    }
    #disc {
        height:100px;
        width:98px;
        top:100px;
        left:-105px;
        z-index:-1;
        -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation:disc 1s linear;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes disc {
        from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
        to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var isOpen = false;
        document.getElementById('cover').addEventListener('click',function() {
            if (!isOpen) {
                document.getElementById('disc').style.top = "0px";
                isOpen = true;
                playSound();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('disc').style.top = "100px";
                isOpen = false;
                stopSound();
            }
        });
        function playSound() {
            document.getElementById('music').play();
        }
        function stopSound() {
            document.getElementById('music').pause();
            document.getElementById('music').currentTime = 0;
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <img id="cover" src="the bloomfields/bloomcover.jpg" alt=""/>
  <img id="disc" src="the bloomfields/record.png" alt=""/>
  <audio id="music">
    <source src="07 Its Complicated.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
  </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: Ah, it feels like the good ol' days were we had Netscape, Mozzy and IE...instead of iFad, iFod and iFone... Standards? Who needs 'em!

Comment: offtopic: Some comments on your programming style. document.getElementById('disc') etc is not a good way of programming (by calling directly to the element) and can break your script easily when the element does not exist or for another reason. I think you must first debug your code for errors, you can enable the debug in the safari config panel or use firefox debug console. Also split your pages into html, css and javascript and use jQuery to reduce errors.

Answer (score 0):

how about you check either your ipad could play mp3 format or not with `canPlayType()` function from audio element, and also you could add the codecs to your audio source that could be better way to define it. `<source src="07 Its Complicated.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"; codecs='mp3'>`.
Then the last, maybe I think your audio source path is not define correctly, "07 Its Complicated.mp3" -> it's contain space characters that the browser could be not render it correctly.